# dojo 1.8 - This time though server, unable to initialise and update ComboBox every time there ia a change in select

Tags: dojo

I was able to able to make it work after I have got help, though I was not able to get ComboBox to display the selected option.

This time i wanted to improvise my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/2CvU2/2/) by  connecting to server, to get the list.
I am wondering why it did not work though I made it as based on my previous jsfiddle.

When I run it with firebug and firephp enabled. I can see that I managed to get the list but was  not able to initate ComboBox. FireBug or FirePhp did not produce any errors. Please see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/9tNhN/11/).

```
meter_Select.on('change', function()
            {
                    console.debug('Selected Card = '+ meter_Select.value);
                    request.post('listofcards.php',{ //'CALL listmfg_codes()'
                    data:{cardX : meter_Select.value},
                    handleAs:"json"
                    }).then(
                    function(response)
                        {
                            var memoStore2 = new Memory({data:response});//ok
                            var card_Select = registry.byId('node_cardSelect');//ok
                            //console.debug('response ='+ memoStore2); 
                            console.debug('card Select(1A) ='+card_Select);//ok

                            if(card_Select)
                            {
                                card_Select.store = memoStore2;
                                console.debug('card Select(1C) ='+card_Select);
                            }//if
                            else
                            {
                                card_Select = new ComboBox({
                                store : memoStore2,
                                searchAttr : "mfg_code"
                                //style:{width:'200px'},
                                },"node_cardSelect");
                                console.debug('card Select(1B) ='+card_Select);
                            }//else

                            //card_Select.startup();
                        },//function(response)

                    function(error)//ok
                        {
                            alert('Getting a list of cards = '+error);
                        }//function(error)
                    )//then
            });//meter_Select.on
```

Comment: What items are returned in your `response` list? They should be objects if you want the list to work with a Memory store. I guess I'm wondering what you mean by "was not able to initiate ComboBox". Does it not get rendered? Does it render but have no items to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, your ComboBox wants an explicit ID. I'm guessing there's some ID conflict going on somewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/9tNhN/13/

Here's the relevant change:

```
        combx = new ComboBox({
            store: memoStore2,
            searchAttr: "mfg_code",
            id: "some_unique_id"
        }, "node_cardSelect");
```

**UPDATE**: the ID field is what you need to use in registry.byId(); the ID after the constructor arguments is where it's placed in the DOM. Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tNhN/14/

Comment: Hi again. Thanks. Adding 'id' does work but again  it goes back to same error if we updated ComboBox from Select. The error says 'Error: Tried to register widget with id==batchSelect but that id is already registered'. I am thinking of using destroyRescursive or domAttr.set. Neither does not seem to work.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Oh... That's interesting. Though the combx is undefined by registry.byID, error won't be displayed. Thanks again for your  helpful tip.